# How to created the feature like Instagram and twitter to mention users and hashtags?

Tags: swift, tags, instagram, mention

When user type "@" in textview then it will display the list of the users and from that list user can select the any one.Same for the Hastag.I able to detect the "@" and "#" and open the list accordingly.I got the issue when user edit the text in the textview like remove or add the text in the textview in that case my logic not work properly. I have stored the index and length of the selected user and make it attributed text but when user edit the text the index will update and my logic goes wrong. Please give the solution for mentions.

I used some code from this : https://github.com/omar14/OEMentions

```
override func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    
    
        let str = String(textView.text)
        var lastCharacter = "nothing"
        
        if !str.isEmpty && range.location != 0{
            lastCharacter = String(str[str.index(before: str.endIndex)])
        }
        
        // Check if there is mentions
        if mentionsIndexes.count != 0 {
            
            for item in mentionsIndexes {
                
                if case item.index ... item.index+item.length = range.location {
                    // If start typing within a mention rang delete that name:
                    
                   textView.replace(textView.textRangeFromNSRange(range: NSMakeRange(item.index, item.length))!, withText: "")
                    
                    mentionsIndexes.removeAll(where: {($0.index == item.index)})
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        if isMentioning {
            if text == " " || (text.count == 0 &&  self.mentionQuery == ""){ // If Space or delete the "@"
                self.mentionQuery = ""
                self.isMentioning = false
                
                self.arrayUsersForTag = []
                
                self.dropDown.hide()
                
            }
            else if text.count == 0 {
                self.mentionQuery.remove(at: self.mentionQuery.index(before: self.mentionQuery.endIndex))
                
                self.arrayUsersForTag = []
                self.dropDown.hide()
                
                self.filterList(query: self.mentionQuery)
                
            }
            else {
                self.mentionQuery += text
                self.filterList(query: self.mentionQuery)
            }
        } else {
            
            /* (Beginning of textView) OR (space then @) OR (Beginning of new line) */
            if text == self.mentionCharater && ( range.location == 0 || lastCharacter == " " || lastCharacter == "\n") {
                
                self.mentionQuery = ""
                
                self.isMentioning = true
                self.startMentionIndex = range.location
                self.filterList(query: self.mentionQuery)
                
            }
        }
    
    
    return true
}

public func filterList(query: String) {
    
    arrayUsersForTag.removeAll()
    
    if query.isEmpty {
        arrayUsersForTag = self.withUsers
    }else{
        
        for object in withUsers {
            if object.fullname.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased()) {
                arrayUsersForTag.append(object)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    self.dropDown.dataSource = []
    for username in arrayUsersForTag {
        dropDown.dataSource.append("\(username.fullname)")
    }
    
    
    
    dropDown.show()
    
}

func dropDownSelection(){
    
    dropDown.selectionAction = { [weak self] (index, item) in
        
        self?.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.becomeFirstResponder()
        
        self?.addMentionToTextView(index)
        
      
        
        self?.dropDown.hide()
    }
}


// Add a mention name to the UITextView
public func addMentionToTextView(_ arrayIndex : Int){
    
    let objUser = arrayUsersForTag[arrayIndex]
    
    let name = objUser.fullname
    
    let mention = "@"+name
    
    let objMention = MentionsIndexes()
    
    objMention.id = objUser.objectId
    
    objMention.index = self.startMentionIndex
    
    objMention.length = mention.count
    
    mentionsIndexes.append(objMention)
    
    if mentionQuery.isEmpty == false{
        
        let query = "@" + self.mentionQuery
        
        let range: Range<String.Index> = self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.text.range(of:  query)!
        
        self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.text.replaceSubrange(range, with: mention)
        
        
        let text =    self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.text.appending(" ")
        
        self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.text = text
        
    }else{
        
        let str = name
        
        let text =  self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.text.appending(str).appending(" ")
        
        self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.text = text
    }
    
    boldTheHastag()
    
    isMentioning = false
    self.mentionQuery = ""
    
}

func boldTheHastag(){
    
    // Add color attribute for the whole text
    
    if let theText = self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.text{
        
        let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: theText)
        
        
        let count = self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.text.count
        
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: chatFont, range: NSMakeRange(0, count))
        
        
        // Add color & font attributes for the mention
        for item in mentionsIndexes {
            
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: boldFont, range: NSMakeRange(item.index, item.length))
        }
        
        
        
        //   attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: notMentionColor, range: NSMakeRange(count, 1))
        
        self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

This code working fine for the normal scenario but if I removed the previously added mention and then try to add mention again then app will crash.

If I delete or add some word in the textview then the index of the text will updated now how I can update the "index" value of each elements of array mentionsIndexes.

If any other solution for mention users with "@" in app like Instagram is available please provide it.

Comment: What is a guy that you so-call 'the Hastag'?  A hashtag?

Comment: show us the code that you have written so far, and where it is not working

Comment: 1. Separate textView.text into components with " ".  2. Get the last component.  3. See if the last component contains the hashtag of your choice.  4. Get the string of the last component without the hashtag of your choice.

Comment: "and my logic goes wrong" What goes wrong exactly? What's your code? Maybe we can help from there. Also, you are not the first one to asked about that feature, maybe some other questions on SO might help...

Answer (score 0):

You need to recalculate ranges based on the changes in the text before the tag. You can add and remove the same length from the index of ranges based on the text entered.